# MediaMetadataRetriever/MediaPlayer fails with .m4b files on LG device

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, lg, mediametadataretriever

I have an app that downloads m4b files. When I try to read the metadata of the file using MediaMetadataRetriever, I get null values. This only happens on LG devices. It doesn't matter if it is Android 4, 5, or 6.

I can get around the problem by using FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever but then the MediaPlayer library cannot play the file.

It works fine on everything except LGE devices. 
It works fine on my Nexus 5x, which I know is made by LG but the Build.BRAND reports it as "google" instead of "LGE"

Any idea why this might be happening and how I can work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to ExoPlayer instead of MediaPlayer and FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever instead of MediaMetadataRetreiver solved my problem.